# XCode 3.2.4 on OSX 10.6 can't find a standard header when building googletest

Tags: xcode, architecture, header, resolution, platform

XCode 3.2.4 on OSX 10.6 (upgraded from 10.5), using GCC 4.2, tells me it can't find .

I know it's located under "/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.4u.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.0.0/i686-apple-darwin8/bits/c++config.h", as well as other target platforms and the 10.5 and 10.6 SDKs; I don't think I need to enumerate them all here, as I suspect what I got going on is standard, but I will provide additional path information on request; There's a lot...

I know this file is also found under "/usr/include/c++/..." as well, but that isn't terribly relevant to this situation, I think...

Anyway, The project is set to build against the 10.6 SDK, though I've tried them all. I don't know or understand how XCode resolves these platform specifics. I've tried building under debug and release, i386 and x86_64, and different compiler versions.

Can someone help me help XCode resolve this? I'd love a fix that didn't involve a hack with symlinks that would lock me into building a particular platform (my fear). I do build across platform architectures so preserving that drop down menu to choose between them is ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the system from scratch instead of upgrading.